# Media Gallery realisation in php

Tags: php, jquery

need to provide an "add from existing" functionality for uploaded images. What is a basic approach to do that? Thought of displaying a modal window but thought that if there will be a lot of images it will definitely pull back the performance. Had anybody a similar task? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this once before, and the best way is to generate thumbnails for each photo to browse in a modal window. You'd also be best off by trying to have some kind of folder architecture, and even have a sort function (date added?).

Have a look at the [jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#demo) plugin, you might be able to script something off of that (ex: every time you click an image it is append to a div on the page for a preview)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Will have a look at that.